# Верстка футера css

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я скажем так новичок в css и у меня не получается сверстать правильно и с сохранением адаптации footer который изображен на скриншоте выше.

Пока у меня получается только так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<footer>
    <div class="silver_stroke"></div>
    <div id="footer_content" class="clearfix">
        <div id="footer_content_items">
            <div class="footer_item">
                <div class="footer_item_icon">
                    <img src="email.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_item_text">
                    <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p>
                    <span>Написать нам</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_item">
                <p>2019 OOO "Анна"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_item">
                <div class="footer_item_icon">
                    <img src="email.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_item_text">
                    <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p>
                    <span>Написать нам</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="silver_stroke"></div>
</footer>
```

style.css

```
footer p, footer span{
    color: white;
}
.footer_item {
    float: left;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Куда я только не пытался вставить margin: 0 auto; или display: flex; и align-items с justify-content: center;

Все без успешно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.footer {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer_content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer_content::before,
.footer_content::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
}

.footer_content::before{
    top: 0;
}

.footer_content::after{
    bottom: 0;
}

.footer_content_items{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 700px){
    .footer_content_items{
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .footer_item{
        width: calc(100% / 3);
    }
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer_content">
        <div class="footer_content_items">
            <div class="footer_item">
                <div class="footer_item_icon">
                    <img src="email.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_item_text">
                    <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p>
                    <span>Написать нам</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_item">
                <p>2019 OOO "Анна"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_item">
                <div class="footer_item_icon">
                    <img src="email.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_item_text">
                    <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p>
                    <span>Написать нам</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: А можете подсказать пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы svg картинка была слева от текста.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вы покажите макет с желаемым результатом, вам Никита Рогачёв сделал то что вам было надо ...отметьте решением или измените ответ

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский а вы можете не лезть?? И если уж придераться, то не совсем что я хотел. Я смысла не вижу вашего комментария. Я просто задал вопрос не мог ли он подсказать. Я уже готов отметить его ответ правильным, но просто возник МАЛЕНЬКИЙ вопросик. Ну ладно если вы хотите пойду задам еще 1 вопрос с этой проблемой. Так же всем лучше будет???????

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вы задали вопрос и вам ответили точь в точь как на вашем скриншоте ...всё остальное надо либо указывать сразу либо пояснить что требуется ...вы же меняете задание на лету ... вопросы плодить смысла нету, достаточно просто показать скриншот с желаемым поведением ... и да и грубить не надо ...я не грубил

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Вопрос был таким "А можете подсказать пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы svg картинка была слева от текста" тоесть я спросил может ли он подсказать. Я не просил его переписать ответь для того чтобы я посчитал его ответ правильным. Я повторяю, что я считаю его ответ правильным ( и да не точь в точь ) и что я решил поинтерисоваться не мог ли бы он подсказать еще 1 маленькую проблемку (и да я ее решил в 1 строчку кода вот почему я посчитал ее маленькой). Я понимаю "сложно" понять это, но будьте добры понять рас уж влезли.

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский все спасибо и вам за компанию, за отличный разговор и за то что настроение испортили. Больше не хочу продолжать "улучшать" свое настроение разговаривая с вами.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков задайте для footer_item display: flex; align-items: center;

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .footer{
  background-color: #444;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 hr{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .content{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .mail{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 }

 .mail img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 15px 5px 0 0;
 }

 .write{
  width: 80%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

.write a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: red;

}
```

```html
 <div class="footer">
  <hr>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="block1 block">
    <div class="mail"><img src="mail.png" alt=""> <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p></div>
    <div class="write"><a href="">Написать нам</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="block2 block">
    <h3>2019 ООО "Компания"</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="block3 block">
    <div class="mail"><img src="mail.png" alt=""> <p>emailpochta@gmail.com</p></div>
    <div class="write"><a href="">Написать нам</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но это не то что мне нужно мне уже помог Rogatnev Nikita.